# What is "(id) sender"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

What does (id)sender in `-(IBAction)PushButton: (id)sender` stand for ?

Comment: This is very, very basic stuff. Have a look at the first page of Apple's introduction to Objective C: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007594

Comment: Super like your link OMZ, thanks a lotttt

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is sender?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842637/what-is-sender)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the object that triggered the event. E.g. sender will be the button that was pressed.

Comment: @Vladimir - does "Sender" here means the action performed by the user ?

Answer (score 2):

`sender` is an object that triggered an action, so in your case it is probably the button that was tapped.

Comment: does "Sender" here means the action performed by the user ?

Comment: To be more exact, id is a non-typed pointer to some object. The idiom (id)sender is a standard signature for a function that receives the object that "triggered" this function call. The calling object is passed as a parameter. In UI objects, it's usually the object that the user interacted with. The reason (UIButton)sender is not used is to allow hooking up many different (UI) sender objects/controls to trigger a single action function.